# RouteValueDictionary an Item with the same key has already been added even with nullcheck

Tags: asp.net-mvc

(Routevalues is an object that i'm unboxing)

```
var dict = ((RouteValueDictionary)this.RouteValues);
```

if (dict[key] == null)
            {
                dict.Add(key, value);
            }

throws an exception: "An Item With the same key has been added" when adding the same key twice in a row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem myself.

Apparantly dict[key] == null is not a valid check to see if a key is present in the dictionary or not!

Should be,

```
if (!dict.ContainsKey(key))
{
                    dict.Add(key, value);
}
```

I think this occurs when the original VALUE of 'key' was an empty string value.
Hope this helps anyone ;-)